# How to logout all sessions created after user password change?

Tags: php, session

I store my session id Redis, my session id is global unique, every time login will generate a new session id, so even same user will still have different session id. So I have no way to destroy the user's session because I have no way to locate it. So how can I design, so as to satisfy my need?

Comment: Unless you have a very badly designed system where session cookie IDs are tied to a particular username, you can't - each browser will get a DIFFERENT session cookie (and therefore different session), and logging out of "session A" will not have any effect on "session B".

Comment: @MarcB *"very badly designed system where session cookie IDs are tied to a particular username"*.  Interesting.  How do sites like facebook expose "session management" screens, where users can log themselves out of other browsers?

Comment: @kdbanman Do you think "very badly designed system where session cookie IDs are tied to a particular username". is an acceptable design?

Comment: I don't know.  see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are a security issue.  I suggest using a library/framework to do it.  If you hand roll your own solution and you do it wrong, you open your users up to session [hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack), [prediction](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Prediction), and/or [fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation).  Those are bad.

If you're using a session library and it's *impossible* to do what you want without seriously monkeying around, there's probably a reason.

If you really want to roll your own rather than using a session library, start [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet).

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- set a timestamp `createdAt` on each session creation
- set a timestamp `sessionExpire` in your user table
- update `user.sessionExpire` in your `resetPassword` method
- on each logged request (so on each refresh or other page browsing, if user session is set), check the `user.sessionExpire` of the logged user and then compare it with the current `session.createdAt`
- if `session.createdAt < user.sessionExpire` then logout

Comment: But every request will query user table, I don't consider it very well.

Comment: I don't see why this could be a real issue... You query your dbs for ... 90%, 95% of each request... Why not the 'user' table ? You want a new feature, so you have to write code, and this code will use resources... Its not so weird.

Comment: What if I use this method: I make two column table in Redis (userId, isSafeLogin) , if user reset password, set isSafeLogin = 0, every refreshing, I will check the field, if 0, clear session, I just cannot find a suitable data structure in Redis, what do you think?

Comment: `session.createdAt < user.sessionExpire` confused about this way.

Comment: its about comparing timestamps (date) use the format in ms to compare integers for example. This simply means `if (was created before expiration date)`